# How do I express "if value is not empty" in the VBA language?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I express the condition "if value is not empty" in the VBA language? Is it something like this?

```
"if value is not empty then..."
Edit/Delete Message
```

Comment: I summon Joel Spolsky!

Comment: Worth noting, that this is something like the null value in other mainstream languages. Emtpy value IS NOT empty string (eg:"")...

Comment: @VajkHermecz Totally wrong ! In VBA a string initializes to "", an integer to  0, a boolean to False....Only Variants have a special behavior...which is still different from SQL `Null`.

Answer (score 107):

Use `Not IsEmpty()`.

For example:

```
Sub DoStuffIfNotEmpty()
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        MsgBox "I'm not empty!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 42):

It depends on what you want to test:

- for a string, you can use `If strName = vbNullString` or `IF strName = ""` or `Len(strName) = 0` (last one being supposedly faster)
- for an object, you can use `If myObject is Nothing`
- for a recordset field, you could use `If isnull(rs!myField)`
- for an Excel cell, you could use `If range("B3") = ""` or `IsEmpty(myRange)`

Extended discussion available [here](http://allenbrowne.com/vba-NothingEmpty.html) (for Access, but most of it works for Excel as well).

Comment: I have a recordset with a `field` `kein aktueller Datensatz`. `Isnull` returns `false` which is `shit`..

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17336418/1705829) is a `SO` solution to check for `null` in a `recordset field`.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
If Len(vValue & vbNullString) > 0 Then
  ' we have a non-Null and non-empty String value
  doSomething()
Else
  ' We have a Null or empty string value
  doSomethingElse()
End If
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use the built-in Format() function?

```
Dim vTest As Variant
vTest = Empty ' or vTest = null or vTest = ""

If Format(vTest) = vbNullString Then
    doSomethingWhenEmpty() 
Else
   doSomethingElse() 
End If
```

Format() will catch empty variants as well as null ones and transforms them in strings.
I use it for things like null/empty validations and to check if an item has been selected in a combobox.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
if var<>"" then
           dosomething
```

or

```
if isempty(thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1").range("a1").value)= false then
```

the ISEMPTY function can be used as well

Answer (score 0):

Alexphi's suggestion is good. You can also hard code this by first creating a variable as a `Variant` and then assigning it to `Empty`. Then do an if/then with to possibly fill it. If it gets filled, it's not empty, if it doesn't, it remains empty. You check this then with `IsEmpty`.

```
Sub TestforEmpty()

    Dim dt As Variant
    dt = Empty

    Dim today As Date
    today = Date
    If today = Date Then
        dt = today
    End If

    If IsEmpty(dt) Then
        MsgBox "It not is today"
    Else
        MsgBox "It is today"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inputbox` function in a for loop:

```
Sub fillEmptyCells()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection
    For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To r.Columns.Count
            If Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
                Cells(i, j).Select
                Cells(i, j).Value = InputBox( _
                    "set value of cell at column " & Cells(1, j).Value & _
                    " and row " & Cells(i, 1))
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution of this issue can be some how easier than we imagine. I have simply used the expression `Not Null` and it worked fine.

```
Browser("micclass").Page("micclass").WebElement("Test").CheckProperty "innertext", Not Null
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Excel.