# Access 2013 Edit Form error 3021

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error, edit, subform

So I've got the code below (not all of it is grey for some reason)

```
Private Sub CmdEdit_Click()

Me.Tableinform.Requery

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.Tableinform.Form.RecordsetClone
    'get data to textbox control
With rs

    If .RecordCount > 0 Then

        With Me.Tableinform.Form.Recordset

        Me.ShowIDbox = .Fields("[ID]").Value
        Me.CompbyDD = .Fields("[Received By]")
        Me.Date1 = .Fields("[Date Received]")
        Me.Date2 = .Fields("[Date Processed]")
        Me.ReqType = .Fields("[Request Type]")
        Me.InsName = .Fields("[Insured Name]")
        Me.RiskNo = .Fields("[Risk Number]")
        Me.EndtRef = .Fields("[Endorsement Reference]")
        Me.EOCNo = .Fields("[EOC Number]")
        Me.Tech = .Fields("[Technician]")
        Me.BillIns = .Fields("[Billing Instructions]")



        Me.Addrecord.Caption = "Update"
        Me.CmdEdit.Enabled = False
        Me.cmdDuplicate.Enabled = True
        Me.CmdDelete.Enabled = True


        End With
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

After one Edit and Update, the edit function throws out Error '3021' No Current Record?

Please show me where I am going wrong with this.

Add/Update button as follows:

```
If Me.ShowIDbox.Value = "" Then


CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO fmdatatable( [Received By], [Date Received], [Date Processed], [Request Type], [Insured Name], [Risk Number], [Endorsement Reference], [EOC Number], [Technician], [Billing Instructions]) " & _
" VALUES ('" & Me.CompbyDD & "','" & Me.Date1 & "','" & Me.Date2 & "','" & Me.ReqType & "','" & Me.InsName & "','" & Me.RiskNo & "','" & Me.EndtRef & "','" & Me.EOCNo & "','" & Me.Tech & "','" & Me.BillIns & "')"

Else

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE fmdatatable SET [Received By]='" & Me.CompbyDD & "'" & _
    ", [Date Received]='" & Me.Date1 & "'" & _
    ", [Date Processed]='" & Me.Date2 & "'" & _
    ", [Request Type]='" & Me.ReqType & "'" & _
    ", [Insured Name]='" & Me.InsName & "'" & _
    ", [Risk Number]='" & Me.RiskNo & "'" & _
    ", [Endorsement Reference]='" & Me.EndtRef & "'" & _
    ", [EOC Number]='" & Me.EOCNo & "'" & _
    ", [Technician]='" & Me.Tech & "'" & _
    ", [Billing Instructions]='" & BillIns & "'" & _
    " WHERE [ID]=" & Me.ShowIDbox.Value

End If

Me.CompbyDD = "-Please Select-"
Me.Date1 = ""
Me.Date2 = ""
Me.ReqType = "-Please Select-"
Me.InsName = ""
Me.RiskNo = ""
Me.EndtRef = ""
Me.EOCNo = ""
Me.Tech = ""
Me.BillIns = "-Please Select-"
Me.ShowIDbox = ""

    Me.Addrecord.Caption = "Add Record"
    Me.CmdEdit.Enabled = True
    Me.cmdDuplicate.Enabled = False
    Me.CmdDelete.Enabled = False
```

Tableinform.Form.Requery

This edit works once, then all subsequent later edits are throwing errors out.

Comment: The code you posted does not edit anything. It just fills some controls (i guess textboxes) with info. Where do you trigger the edit?

Comment: Yeah it does, then those text boxes get edited and an update button is pressed, which works, then all subsequent presses of 'edit' run error messages.

Comment: Is this code all the code in Edit button? What is the code in Update button? This question is too open now to make an answer

Comment: Edited as per request

Comment: As a little further context, my [ID] field is an autonumber generated when each record is created, in the form of sequential integers (1,2,3 etc) to act as a unique key for each entry because no other part of the data being entered is inherently unique.

Comment: Ok, and what line appears highlighted when the error appears?

Comment: As a Run-Time '3021' No Current Record it highlights this:

        Me.ShowIDbox = .Fields("[ID]").Value            from the Edit macro

Comment: Ok, have you checked the value of `rs.Eof`? That error probably means you went all over the recordset. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336316/run-time-error-3021-no-current-record

Comment: That didn't appear to do anything, no message box popped up?

Comment: And what is the value of rs.Eof when the error appears?

Comment: It doesn't give one? It just goes to the same error and highlights the line:         Me.ShowIDbox = .Fields("[ID]").Value