# Excel VBA Object required error on VBA Script do duplicate lines while counter

Tags: vba, excel, do-while

I'm trying to make a VBA script in an Excel document that loops through each line for an amount of time (column 3) and writes each of this line to the columns E, F, and G looking exactly like the line does in the Original input. In the end giving a total of 1050 lines with the example below.

The input looks like this, in Cell A, B and C, where column 1 is CompanyName, Column 2 is a CompanyNumber and column 3 is the amount.

`CompanyName1   9910483 300
CompanyName2    9910477 250
CompanyName3    9910620 500`

result:

`CompanyName1   9910483 300
CompanyName1    9910483 300
CompanyName1    9910483 300
CompanyName1    9910483 300
CompanyName1    9910483 300
CompanyName1    9910483 300
etc to 300 lines, then next line item for amount times`

The VBA code I made looks like this:

```
Sub DoWhileItemsAndAmount()

    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim rowCounter As Integer
    Dim column1 As String
    Dim column2 As String
    Dim column3 As Integer

    counter = 1
    rowCounter = 1


    Do While Cells(rowCounter, "C") Is Not Null

        column1 = Cells(rowCounter, "A").Value
        column2 = Cells(rowCounter, "B").Value
        column3 = Cells(rowCounter, "C").Value

        Do While counter < column3
            Cells(counter, "E").Value = column1
            Cells(counter, "F").Value = column2
            Cells(counter, "G").Value = column3
            counter = counter + 1
        Loop

        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

This results in error "Object required" running the macro. Telling nothing else like error codes etc. I like to believe that the script is in the right direction.

I know it doesn't sound logical, but a program we use expects this output as input.

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: i changed the code to this and now it works

`Sub DoWhileItemsAndAmount()

```
' Declare vars
Dim counter As Integer
Dim rowTeller As Integer
Dim savePos As Integer
Dim column1 As String
Dim column2 As String
Dim column3 As Integer

' Set vars
counter = 0
savePos = 1
rowCounter = 1

' set errorcatch
On Error GoTo Errorcatch

' do while cell C is Not Empty
Do While ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(rowCounter, "C").Value <> ""
    column1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(rowCounter, "A").Value
    column2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(rowCounter, "B").Value
    column3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(rowCounter, "C").Value
    counter = 0
    ' do while teller smaller then value in field
    Do While counter < column3

        ' add values to other fields incremental
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(savePos, "E").Value = column1
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(savePos, "F").Value = column2
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(savePos, "G").Value = column3
        counter = counter + 1
        savePos = savePos + 1
    Loop
    rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
Loop
```

Exit Sub
' show msgbox on error
Errorcatch:
 MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
`

This seems to work, had to build in a savePos to have it remember the line its at. the answer of iDevlop fixed the issue of the script not running.

Comment: on which line  does the error happen ?

Comment: @iDevlop I am sure it's the: `Do While Cells(rowCounter, "C") Is Not Null`. Possibly the OP is thinking `Cells()` returns an Object rather than a Variant. Probably a `Do While Not isEmpty(Cells(rowCounter, "C"))` would do

Comment: .@iDevlop: The line was not showing.
@vba4all: This removed the previous error, thanks, now however i get a messagebox showing the error sign and the value 400, not even a messagebox title. Working with Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if a cell is empty, you can use `Range(xx) <> ""` or `cell(x,y)<>""`
See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2009754/78522).

Comment: Thanks, your solution fixed the error. Had to put in a savePos counter to have it not start in field 1 every loop. Thanks for the support!